# Prove a relationship in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Along the way in solving a problem, I got stuck in proving that the following should hold:
$$\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}\frac{\binom{R}{\omega}\binom{N-R}{n-\omega}}{\binom{N}{n}}
    =\frac{\binom{R}{0}\binom{N-R}{n-0}}{\binom{N}{n}} +\frac{\binom{R}{1}\binom{N-R}{n-1}}{\binom{N}{n}} +\frac{\binom{R}{2}\binom{N-R}{n-2}}{\binom{N}{n}} +\frac{\binom{R}{3}\binom{N-R}{n-3}}{\binom{N}{n}} +...+ \frac{\binom{R}{R}\binom{N-R}{n-R}}{\binom{N}{n}}=1$$. This is equivalent to $$\binom{R}{0}\binom{N-R}{n-0}+\binom{R}{1}\binom{N-R}{n-1}+\binom{R}{2}\binom{N-R}{n-2}+\binom{R}{3}\binom{N-R}{n-3}+...+\binom{R}{R}\binom{N-R}{n-R}={\binom{N}{n}}$$.

I tried to decompose the binomial coefficients. It did not lead to the expected result. Have you encountered this relation ? Do you have any suggestion how to prove that ?

Comment: This is Vandermonde's identity.

Comment: You could just  move the denominator $N \choose n$ outside the sum, and what's left is pretty easy to sum.


The terms left inside the sum just equal the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x)^N$ i.e $ N \choose n$